Joystick not working anymore
I have installed Ubuntu-22.04-LTS on a Steam Deck half a year ago.
I could read the joystick-input from the built-in joysticks of the Steam Deck without any problems.
However, since last week reading the joysticks does not work anymore.
I usually read the joysticks with the python-libraries "pyjoystick", "pyglet", or "pygame".
For troubleshooting, i also used the ubuntu-application jstest and jstest-gtk.
The joystick is definitely still detected and shows the correct information:

Steam Deck
Device: /dev/input/js0
Axes: 10
Buttons: 24

I also tried these troubleshooting-steps from the kernel-documentation: joystick-doc
I even set up a clean environment with another Steam Deck that I had lying around.
First, I installed Ubuntu-22.04-LTS -> did not work again.
Afterwards, I tried Ubuntu-24.04-LTS -> did not work.
Does anyone know what causes this problem. Seems like a driver issue.
In the original Steam-Deck-OS, the joysticks worked without any problems. (Steam-Deck-OS now uninstalled)
Driver-version according to jstest:
jstest /dev/input/js0
Driver version is 2.1.0.

Information about the apt joystick-package:
madas@madas-Jupiter:~$ apt show joystick
Package: joystick
Version: 1:1.8.1-2build1
Priority: extra
Section: universe/utils
Origin: Ubuntu
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Stephen Kitt <skitt@debian.org>
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Installed-Size: 206 kB
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.34), libsdl2-2.0-0 (>= 2.0.12)
Recommends: evtest, inputattach
Homepage: https://sourceforge.net/projects/linuxconsole/
Download-Size: 47,5 kB
APT-Manual-Installed: no
APT-Sources: http://at.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/universe amd64 Packages
Description: set of testing and calibration tools for joysticks
 Some useful tools for using joysticks:
  evdev-joystick(1) - joystick calibration tool
  ffcfstress(1)     - force-feedback stress test
  ffmvforce(1)      - force-feedback orientation test
  ffset(1)          - force-feedback configuration tool
  fftest(1)         - general force-feedback test
  jstest(1)         - joystick test
  jscal(1)          - joystick calibration tool
 .
 evtest and inputattach, which used to be part of this package, are now
 available separately.

